# How do you upgrade gitosis?

Tags: git, gitosis

I *had* a working gitosis installation on debian lenny, but the server got updated, and now when i try to push/pull/fetch, the connection times out. It would probably be a good idea to update to the latest build of gitosis, but I can't find anything on how to upgrade the software. How would I upgrade gitosis? Do I just reinstall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply download the latest source code, compile, and make install to replace the old version.

Comment: I am going to give this a try tonight. Thanks!